# Resend contract using docusign SOAP API

Tags: docusign

I have integrated salesforce with doucusign using SOAP API
I have to resend contract

```
/*Method to resend Contract from Docusign*/
```

webService static string resendContractStatusDocusign( Id contractID){
    System.Debug('## ContractID '+ contractID);
    Contract__c contract = [SELECT Document_Key__c,Sent_Using_Test_Setting__c FROM Contract__c WHERE Id =: contractID];

```
ApiDocusign.EnvelopeStatus status;
ApiDocuSign.APIServiceSoap dsApiSend = new ApiDocuSign.APIServiceSoap();
    String userId = docusignTestSettingsList[0].Test_Docusign_UserId__c;
    String password = docusignTestSettingsList[0].Test_Docusign_Password__c;
    String integratorsKey = docusignTestSettingsList[0].Test_Docusign_Integrator_Key__c;

    testAuth = '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>' + userId + '</Username><Password>' + password + '</Password><IntegratorKey>' + integratorsKey + '</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>';

    dsApiSend.endpoint_x = docusignTestSettingsList[0].Test_Docusign_Webservice_Url__c;
    dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
    dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('X-DocuSign-Authentication', testAuth);
    ApiDocusign.Correction correction = new ApiDocusign.Correction();
    correction.EnvelopeID = contract.Document_Key__c;

 /*   ApiDocusign.RecipientCorrection recipientCorrection = new ApiDocusign.RecipientCorrection();
    recipientCorrection.Resend = True;
    ApiDocusign.ArrayOfRecipientCorrection rcpCorrections = new ApiDocusign.ArrayOfRecipientCorrection();
    rcpCorrections.RecipientCorrection = new ApiDocusign.RecipientCorrection[]{recipientCorrection};
    correction.RecipientCorrections = rcpCorrections; */

    status = dsApiSend.RequestStatusEx(contract.Document_Key__c);

    ApiDocusign.CorrectionStatus correctionStatus = dsApiSend.CorrectAndResendEnvelope(correction);
    system.debug('##correctionStatus'+correctionStatus );
return null;
```

}

But I am not able to resend email not understanding what mistake i ma doing
Following is the response

```
##correctionStatus CorrectionStatus:[EnvelopeSettingsCorrectionStatus=null, EnvelopeSettingsCorrectionStatus_type_info=(EnvelopeSettingsCorrectionStatus, http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0, null, 0, 1, false), Expirations=null, Expirations_type_info=(Expirations, http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0, null, 0, 1, false), RecipientCorrectionStatuses=null, RecipientCorrectionStatuses_type_info=(RecipientCorrectionStatuses, http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0, null, 0, 1, false), Reminders=null, Reminders_type_info=(Reminders, http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0, null, 0, 1, false), apex_schema_type_info=(http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0, true, false), field_order_type_info=(EnvelopeSettingsCorrectionStatus, RecipientCorrectionStatuses, Reminders, Expirations)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the portion of code that is intended to actually apply recipient change is commented out, so effectively no changes have been made to this envelope. Try applying any change to the envelope (even if it is the same recipient information), then confirm the envelope is resent.

Comment: I have to resend contract without changing any of the recipient information. My requirement is to send a contract copy in case if user haven’t received any mail or have deleted mail. How this can be done? –